# Weird encoded characters coming from Russia

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, solr, encode

We've been seeing a lot of weird encoded characters show up on our logging reports primarily coming from Russia.  Could this just be a form of bots or crawlers that are spamming our site with malicious intent?

I've tried to google but it hasn't been much help.  Has anyone encountered something similar?

```
  "SearchWithinKWs": [
    "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"
  ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

25 is the ascii value of `%`, so my initial guess would be that these are automated bots trying to trigger errors based on sending a lot of `%%%%%%%%<char>` requests [to attempt to expose encoding / escaping errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) - either in the frontend or the backend.

But the repeating use of `%25` could also mean that this logged string is simply passed through a lot of services that all do their own escaping, then gets dropped somewhere long the line.

Since (almost) each char contain the same number of escapes:

```
2525252525252525252525d0
252525252525252525252596
2525252525252525252525d0
2525252525252525252525b8
2525252525252525252525d0
2525252525252525252525b4
2525252525252525252525d0
2525252525252525252525ba
2525252525252525252525d0
2525252525252525252525be
2525252525252525252525d0
2525252525252525252525b5
252525252525252525252b
2525252525252525252525d0
2525252525252525252525bc
2525252525252525252525d1
25252525252525252525258b
2525252525252525252525d0
2525252525252525252525bb
2525252525252525252525d0
2525252525252525252525be
2525252525252525252525bb
2525252525252525252525d0
```

The single value that stands out is 0x2b, which represents '+' - which in turn is used to escape a space.

If we ignore all the `25` values, which probably are multiple layers of `%` encoded and lost, we end up with something that seems to resemble UTF-8 characters (the repeating d0 is a good hint of this). We can decode the bytes as UTF-8 in python and see if we get anything useful:

```
>>> b"\xd0\x96\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb4\xd0\xba\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb5 \xd0\xbc\xd1\x8b\xd0\xbb\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbb".decode("utf-8")
'Жидкое мылол'
```

Since I have no knowledge of Russian what so ever, I [used Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/%D0%96%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BB) to at least get a hint about what it could be. Google translate tells me that this is a query for `Liquid Soap`. Detergent?

If that's malicious or not would depend on the context, and where all these % encodings break down.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is actually really helpful.  I'll look further into this.